# FormArray. Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I want to output a form in which one field is an array, and for each element of the array I need to output my inputs.

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const fb = this.fb;
  this.editForm = this.fb.group({
    country: fb.control(null),
    identifiers: this.fb.array([
       this.fb.group({
         codeIdentifier: fb.control(null),
         numIdentifier: fb.control(null),
       })
    ]),
 });
 this.organizationService.getOneById(this.id).subscribe((organization: Organization) => {
    let ids: any[] = [];
    organization.identifiers.forEach(item => {
       let id: any = { "codeIdentifier": "", "numIdentifier": "" };
       id.codeIdentifier = item.typeIdentifier.code;
       id.numIdentifier = item.numIdentifier;
       ids.push(id);
    });
     this.editForm.setControl('identifiers', this.fb.array(ids || []));
 })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div [formGroup]="editForm">
  <ng-container formArrayName="identifiers">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let identifier of identifiers.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="text" formControlName="codeIdentifier">
      <input type="text" formControlName="numIdentifier">
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Got error:

> Cannot find control with path: 'identifiers -> 0 -> codeIdentifier'

Comment: try using `formControlName='{{i}}`

Comment: why are you using `div` with `formControlName`?  change that to `input`

Comment: it's the same thing, nothing changes

Comment: I would recommend change `formControlName="typeIdentifier"` to `formControlName="codeIdentifier"` on your html template

Comment: @AymenKanzari have you solved your problem. my problem is if single formgroup is added to a form array, shows `Cannot find control with path`. but if multiple formgroup or no formgroup added there is no error.

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to set it with the `group` inside the `array` as you built it, like that:

```
this.editForm.setControl('identifiers',
  this.fb.array(ids.map(
      id => this.fb.group({codeIdentifier: id})
    ) || [])
);

this.editForm.setControl('identifiers',
  this.fb.array(ids.map(
      id => this.fb.group({numIdentifier: id})
    ) || [])
);
```

- I didn't entirely understood your `Objects` structure, but this is the way to build the Control Array back to view for Edit/Update purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) ... I was passing array of objects ( [{text: 'asfd'}] ) and not array of form groups of such objects - for example like this: arrayOfObjects.map(obj => this.formBuilder.group(obj)) ... :)

Comment: Thank you I have been sleepless on wondering what's wrong. This answer solved my problems. I owe you a nice cup of coffee

Answer (score 2):

identifiers is nothing in your code (well the name of a property of a formArray)

You can choose

1.-put a getter in your .ts

```
get identifiers()
{
    return this.editForm.get('identifiers") as FormArray
}
```

2.-change your .html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let identifier of editForm.get('identifiers").controls;
           let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
```